# Add http header to all requests to GeckoFx

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, geckofx

I am trying to figure out a way to add a custom http header to all requests made through geckoFX. I tried to add a header using

```
GeckoMIMEInputStream strea=new GeckoMIMEInputStream();
strea.AddHeader("head","val"); 
geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com",GeckoLoadFlags.None,"",null,strea);
```

I need a way to add a custom header, to absolutely ALL requests made when going to a webpage.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement your own observer (nsIObserver interface) to intercept the http-on-modify-request notification and there add headers.

```
class Observer: nsIObserver
{
    public void Observe(nsISupports aSubject, string aTopic, string aData)
    {
        var request = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIHTTPChannel>(aSubject);
        request.SetRequestHeader(name, value, merge);
    }
}
```

and register it

```
Xpcom.GetService<nsIObserverService>("@mozilla.org/observer-service;1").AddObserver(new Observer(), "http-on-modify-request", false);
```

Comment: in `request.SetRequestHeader(name, value, merge);` how do you set the `name` and `value`? How to convert string to `Gecko.nsACStringBase`

Comment: var name = new nsACString(name_string);

Comment: Also how do I get a certain header from requests? I tried `request.GetRequestHeader(name, strRef);`, but it throws an exception: `ClassFactory cannot supply requested class`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ObserveHttpModifyRequest` event:

```
var browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
browser.UseHttpActivityObserver = true;
browser.ObserveHttpModifyRequest += 
    (sender, e) => e.Channel.SetRequestHeader(name, value, merge: true);
```

For more information check [nsIRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/NsIRequest) and [nsIHttpChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIHttpChannel) pages on MDN.